# python/flask sql result to JSON no object keys?

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I am relatively new to Python and Flask so sorry if this is very basic. I am running a query in my method like so:

```
    @app.route('/coreteams')
    def coreteams():
    db = FlaskApp.db_connect()
    coreteams = db.execute(text(
        "SELECT service_users.id AS user_id, core_teams.service_user, core_teams.staff_name , core_teams.role, staff_list.id AS staff_id, staff_list.status, core_teams.workbase" \
        " FROM core_teams" \
        " LEFT JOIN staff_list" \
        " ON staff_list.name = core_teams.staff_name" \
        " LEFT JOIN service_users" \
        " ON service_users.name = core_teams.service_user" \
        " WHERE staff_list.status <> 'Left'" \
        " AND staff_list.status <> 'Name Changed';"
    )).fetchall()

    return jsonify(core=coreteams)
```

The result I get is similar to this:

```
{
  "core": [
    [
      3, 
      "Phillippa *********", 
      "Abbey *********", 
      "Activities", 
      2, 
      "Probation", 
      "The ************"
    ], 
    [
      60, 
      "Raymond ***********", 
      "Adam ************", 
      "Documentation", 
      8, 
      "Current", 
      "Old ****"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I would have imagined it should be thing more along the lines of this:

```
{
  "core": [
    [
      "staff_id" : 3, 
      "staff_name" : "P H", 
      "user_name" : "A C", 
      "role" : "Activities", 
      "user_id" : 2, 
      "status" :"Probation", 
      "workbase" : "Location 1"
    ]
 ]
}
```

So basically the return JSON also containing the column names from the database? Is this possible?

Comment: What database driver are you using? It should offer a cursor that returns dictionaries.

Comment: mssql+pymssql it is a MS database

Comment: I missed the SQLAlchemy tag. You can pass `as_dict=True` to a pymssql cursor, but SQLAlchemy won't give you named columns for text queries. You'd have to use SQLAlchemy core or the ORM.